# Will a 3D CSS transform continue even when a parent element is hidden from view?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

In Webkit, will a 3D CSS transform set to repeat indefinitely, continue even when it or a parent element is hidden from view by styling (CSS)?

The reason I ask is that I am seeing unexpectedly high CPU usage on a page I am developing.

If anyone knows a good way to diagnose this issue (for example visualizing where CPU cycles are going on a page, as opposed to a blanket CPU usage per tab), I would be very grateful.

Anecdotal evidence (removal of the hidden CSS animation) would suggest that the animations *do* run in the background. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can debug this kind of situation with the developer tools

chrome / safari right click inspect element.

Go to the timeline tab and click on record, after that you can see what the browser is doing internally.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate dynamic removal of the CSS class linked to the animation.

Answer (score 2):

In chrome 16.0.912.75, at least CSS animations appear to continue even when the element is set to visibility:hidden;. Setting display:none appears to resolve the issue.